# SignalR vs SignalR Core performance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I am finding that SignalR over AspNetCore is WAY slower than the orignal ASP.NET implementation.

I have some heavy calls that take maybe 7 or 8 seconds to finish serialization on ASP.NET, these same calls take twice as long on AspNetCore.

When I run this heavy call 3 times in parallel I can get times around 12 seconds on ASP.NET, but 28 seconds on AspNetCore.

My research indicates that AspNetCore is supposed to be much lighter and faster but I'm not seeing it in practice.  Has anyone else seen this?  Is it possible I have mis-configured AspNetCore in some way to account for this?

Comment: Share us how you configured SignalR in Core. Share us complete demo to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Can you share the source on github?